# Mock inner final object

Tags: java, unit-testing, mocking, mockito

I am trying to write a test for pre-existing class.

```
class ClassToBeTested {

  private final Obj1 a;

  ClassToBeTested(String anotherVariable) {

     a = new Obj1(anotherVariable);
  }

 public void methodToBeTested() {

     if(invokeSomeOtherMethod()) {
          a.getAnotherVariable().doSomething();
     } 
 }

 public boolean invokeSomeOtherMethod() { 
         // return true or false based on some logic
 }

 Obj1 getObj1() {
     return a;
 }

}
```

Below is my Test Class:

```
class TestClass {


    @Test
    public void testMethod() {

        ClassToBeTested x = new ClassToBeTested("someString");
        ClassToBeTested spyX = spy(x);
        doReturn(false).when(spyX).invokeSomeOtherMethod();

        spyX.methodToBeTested();
        verify(spyX, times(1)).getObj1().doSomething();

    }
}
```

This is my understanding:
Since the obj1 is private final object which is created in the class constructor, it neither be directly accessed in the test method nor force the spyObject to use a mocked version of obj1.

Also since verify() requires mocked version of obj1, it throws me an error:
`Wanted But Not invoked: x.getObj1(), however there are otherInteractions with this mock: x.invokeSomeOtherMethod()`

Is my understanding wrong? What would be the way to test testMoethod()?

Comment: Modify constructor so that `a` is injected?

Comment: I would like to avoid that as it would require changes across multiple files in the project. Also initialization of a is not directly dependent on the code that is invoking it as `anotherVariable` is just a string that is not currently being used.

Comment: I don't understand your code.  Your class shows just the one constructor - there's no constructor without parameters.  But you're using a constructor without parameters in your test method.  Which one is right?

Comment: Sorry...my Bad... Rectified it... There is constructor with one string parameter.

Comment: Your issue is that you're calling `verify` on the `spyX` object, whereas you're trying to verify a method call on the `Obj1` object.  Probably the simplest thing to do would be to add a second constructor, where you pass in an `Obj1` instead of a `String`.  Then use that second constructor in your test, and pass in a mock `Obj1`, which you can then verify.

Comment: Thanks for the timely accept.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to not understand how to do proper **dependency injection**. You don't need to change all your code in order to make it easier to test - just use constructor telescoping for example:

```
class ClassToBeTested {

  private final Obj1 a;

  public ClassToBeTested(String anotherVariable) {
   this(new Obj1(anotherVariable));
  }

  ClassToBeTested(Obj1 a) {
    this.a = a;
  }
```

Done. Now you have a package-protected constructor that you can use to insert an instance of **a** directly. And all your other production code can stay like it is.

In other words: don't "fix" your design problems by using mocking framework tricks.